# Amazon Web Services (AWS) Cognito error "Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool."

Tags: java, eclipse, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito

I am running [this app from GitHub](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cognito-java-desktop-app) which allows a user to sign up and sign in to a Cognito Client App. I am using Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers Version: 2019-03 (4.11.0), Build id: 20190314-1200. I have ensured that I put all the necessary credentials accurately. I am able to sign up using both the form and the console.

When I try to sign in, I get an error in the console that says, "Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool." using both form and console.

I have tried the answers on other posts on stack**overflow** similar to this question. The cause of my error is different than the causes in those other posts.

The Console View and the code below are both when I use the form version of the app.

Here is a screenshot of the form:

[image]

Here is what the console shows, without the details of the error:

> {"sub":"52c99df9-f7ef-42b2-9127-9675ba4e2414","email_verified":false,"iss":"https://cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_d0Y5gS66r","phone_number_verified":true,"cognito:username":"*****","aud":"4feegfdtp0dbt9atu56vruuv37","event_id":"c77eff2c-01ad-42c3-8dac-a4849dc297c6","token_use":"id","auth_time":1560793958,"phone_number":"+***********","exp":1560797558,"iat":1560793958,"email":"********"}
>
> User is authenticated:eyJraWQiOiJ4K1piekppSWN4RjZtbDVENjVSQXAySlBOQ0ROK2FmU3Fpc1BnSDE0c3ZvPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.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.BqyjJJgOZcQP7yUDd3wDrrK4pNRs8BE8RvBzl2vIz248f3rgQ4fn1cd54azjtlplGkthbB0zA9xcd7gPJzqffd-3wS9RFevxkT4LfSiGF1UXGpIqHH_GhbMHA4dG6nKqBOmInvcn9gR1oblBszdbvUxE1poyP3MLvIi64vRvYm1P2kdikWlXl7qKH_RFivEmRMbpd4xpXH6Gjv3hxE6w2vn4O3oZkwz5eY-djUfbwy_uhItycPB3yZLGS8LU55vkrvyJrzHQLDu1U5AvkHGLZv1H7GveHm36RRwSGH5ZkCrtfkolRBN7wkqq9pGhh3jccqHN6Ml5L3XmH3irFNikfw
>
> provider = cognito-idp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/us-east-1_d0Y5gS66r
>
> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread"
>
> com.amazonaws.services.cognitoidentity.model.NotAuthorizedException:
>
> Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.
>
> (Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity; Status Code: 400; Error Code:
>
> NotAuthorizedException; Request ID:
>
> b295ece8-9128-11e9-bb89-5d1e066e532b)

Here is the code for the sign in button that I press to sign in:

```
signin_button = new Button("Sign-In");
Label auth_message = new Label("");
signin_button.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
    String result = helper.ValidateUser(Username.getText(), Password.getText());
    if (result != null) {
        System.out.println("User is authenticated:" + result);
        auth_message.setText("User is authenticated");
        JSONObject payload = CognitoJWTParser.getPayload(result);
        String provider = payload.get("iss").toString().replace("https://", "");

        // Daniel Brower
        System.out.println("provider = " + provider);

        Credentials credentails = helper.GetCredentials(provider, result);


        ShowUserBuckets(credentails);
    } else {
        System.out.println("Username/password is invalid");
        auth_message.setText("Username/password is invalid");
    }

});
```

The line of code with my name in the comment above it is code I put in myself.

I'm having trouble figuring out from what provider the token is from.

Here is a screenshot of my identity providers page in Cognito Console. I haven't selected any. Nothing says that there is an identity provider.

[image]

The error message says "Service: AmazonCognitoIdentity" in it. I think the provider would be Cognito Identity Provider. I even found classes with that name in it.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I had the wrong value for some reason to Cognito Console->Federated Identities->Edit identity pool->Cognito->App client id

I don't know how I got it wrong. I changed it to match the correct one of the Identity Pool.

Comment: Thank you so much!! In my case I just forgot to add the new Client App in the "Edit identity pool"

Comment: In all honesty, I though that "Federated Identities" were only necessary when you want to give users access to AWS resources. So, I didn't even have federated identites set up.

Answer (score 9):

This issue happens if your Federated Identity configuration is missing on your pool.

`Open Federated Identities => Authentication providers`

On the Cognito section change values as below

```
User Pool ID
ex: test:us-east-1_Ab129f000
App client id
ex: test:7lhlkkfbfb4q5kpp90urf000
```

That should be fix your issue

Comment: I had to do this manually for my aws amplify deployment for some reason. Thanks for the guidance.