# Cognito AWS: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk, aws-identitypools

I'm currently grabbing the idToken from an authenticated cognito user to use as credentials for making a s3Client command.

I receive the idToken which looks correct when decoded, and pass it to new CognitoIdentityClient
but when I reach the s3Client.send command I get this error:

`NotAuthorizedException: Token is not from a supported provider of this identity pool.`

I've checked that the User Pool ID and App Client Id connected to the identity pool is correct.

[other solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56637042/amazon-web-services-aws-cognito-error-token-is-not-from-a-supported-provider) did not quite help.

My code:

```
      const session = await Auth.currentSession();
      const idToken = session.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
     
      if (idToken) {
        const credentials = fromCognitoIdentityPool({
          client: new CognitoIdentityClient({ region: "eu-central-1" }),
          identityPoolId: "eu-central-1:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
          logins: {
            'cognito-idp.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/eu-central-1_xxxxxxxxx': idToken,
          },
        });

        const s3Client = new S3Client({ credentials, region: "eu-central-1" });

        s3Client
          .send(
            new GetObjectCommand({
              Bucket: "MY_BUCKET",
              Key: "MY_KEY",
            }),
          )
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
          });
      }
```

and package.json:

```
   "dependencies": {
    "@aws-amplify/ui-react": "^4.3.6",
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity": "^3.278.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.278.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity": "^3.278.0",
    "aws-amplify": "^5.0.12",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1322.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "i": "^0.3.7",
    "npm": "^9.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
```